# It it okay to access an optional variable with question mark without exclamation mark?

Tags: swift

I know that an optional constant or variable with a question mark needs an exclamation mark to access its value. then, I tried to exam it with the following code.

```
var aaa:String? = "3"
println("aaa = \(aaa!)")
```

Yes. It was okay. It printed "3" on Console Output. and next exam I tried like that

```
var aaa:String? = "3"
println("aaa = \(aaa)")
```

It also printed "3" without any error message. It worked well.

I learned about `Forced Unwrapping` that en exclamation mark is needed to access to a value of Optional. But, I could access it without the mark. Is it right? I wonder what is wrong. Am I misunderstanding Optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Println()` will print the value if it has any otherwise it will print nil. Just to understand things better just try to assign value of `aaa` to another string variable. It will throw error that *value of optional type not unwrapped*.

```
var aString:NSString? = "Hello"
var bString = aString // Compiler allows, as you are assigning to optional type again.
var cString:NSString = aString // Compiler throws error. You cannot assign optional type without unwrapping.
```

So to answer your question you need to use `!` to get the value.

Edit:

```
var foo:Bool?
foo = false

if foo { // This always evaluates to `True`
    ...
}

if foo! { // This condition will now fail
    ...
}
```

The reason `foo` evaluated to `True` is because it was not unwrapped. Since its not unwrapped its just checking whether it has a value or not(true or false does not matter).

When `foo` was unwrapped it returned a value `False` hence the second if condition failed.

Answer (score 5):

You are correctly understanding Optionals and Forced Unwrapping. The reason that you can print the optional variable is that the type `Optional` can also be printed. If you print an `Optional` instead of the real value, it will either print the value if it has one, or "nil" if it doesn't.

Also, just in case you don't realize it. Forced Unwrapping will cause the whole program to crash if the optional is nil at the time. To be safer, you should use [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_432):

```
var aaa: String? = "3"
if let actualString = aaa {
    // actualString becomes a non-optional version of aaa
    // if aaa were nil, this block would not be run at all
    println(actualString)
}
```

Also, some extra information about the printing of instances. Printing uses the protocol `Printable` which defines a `description` property. Anything that implements this protocol can customize the way they print out. `Optional` has its own implementation of this protocol which is how it decides to either print "nil" or the `description` of the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

The `println` function is a special case. It automatically unwraps the variable for you. If the variable were `nil`, it would print `nil`. In other contexts, you **do** need to unwrap the variable yourself.